# Having unique records based on specific columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, unique, rows

Please I need to have unique rows based on some specific columns in my table.

This is my table below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_StudentProgress]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FK_ClassId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StudentName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [AdmissionNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Term] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Fk_SubjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Assignment1] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Assignment2] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Assignment3] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Note] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [CA1] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [CA2] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Exam] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [TotalScore] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [ClassName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [FK_Session] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateEntered] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT ('1900-01-01T00:00:00.000'),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.tbl_StudentProgress] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The specific columns are `FK_ClassId`, `StudentName`, `AdmissionNumber`, `Term`, `FK_SubjectId` and `FK_Session`.

Please how can I do this?

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want a unique constraint:

```
alter table tbl_StudentProgress add constraint unq_tbl_StudentProgress_6
    unique (FK_ClassId, StudentName, AdmissionNumber, Term, FK_SubjectId, FK_Session);
```

Comment: Exactly @Gordon, i just didn't know how to ask it better. Thanks for your reply